# iPhone app freezes briefly during fetch for content updates. Can this be fixed?

Tags: ios4

I have an iPhone app that displays blog articles. You can drill into one article and look at it's entire story. At the bottom of the story are comments from other users.

The app fetches latest comments from the server every 15 seconds. If there are more comments returned, the app prepends them to the top of the list. This is all working pretty well.

The problem is that, whenever the app does the fetch (every 15 seconds), the app sort of "freezes" for about 1 second, sometimes 2 seconds. If you are scrolling through the comments, this delay becomes pretty noticeable because the scrolling stops in place while the update processes.

This iPhone app is being developed by a third-party dev team who is remote. I have asked the dev team to stop the "freeze" from happening, but they insist that it's normal functionality when updating a table in the iPhone.

I am not an iPhone developer and have no knowledge or experience of working in that environment, so I am not able to really argue against this. But, I have to imagine that there is some way to do a background fetch and update of the table without causing lag to the user experience.

Does anyone have any thoughts around this? Are there techniques that the devs could be employing to create a smooth experience during the update process?

Answer (score 0):

They are fetching comments in synchronous mode in which UI will hang until it downloads completely. Tell them to download content in asynchronous mode so that it will fetch comments in background and UI scrolling will be smooth then.

Example Codes:

```
[connection startAsynchronous];

https://gist.github.com/fspeirs/106457

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use
```

Let me know if you find any difficulty.